# Samba4: Set unix properties of account

Tags: samba, user-accounts, samba4

I've upgraded to samba4 (4.3) and now I can use the samba-tool to create users, add them to groups, ... but I can't set the unix attributes of user account.

I tried looking around samba-tool but I haven't found any way to do it. SSSD is configured to show only accounts that have all the properties defined and I can only add them using the windows rsat.

How to set the user uid and primary group for a samba account from the command line?